# What is the equivalent of a javascript callable function as a class parameter in python?

Tags: javascript, python

In javascript, I do can add a function parameter to my function class like so:

```js
const MyFunc = function(){
  const myfunc = this
  myfunc.hi = () => {
    console.log('hi')
  }
}

const myFunc = new MyFunc()
myFunc.hi()
```

What is the equivalent in python?

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, hi):
        self.hi = def func():
            print('hi')
```

Comment: Why not just make it a method on the class? Even in JavaScript, `hi` should be a method on the prototype.

Comment: Yes - that's what I'm trying to understand how to do. :)  I'm new to python.

Comment: Then use a _tutorial_, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `lambda`.

```py
self.hi = lambda: print('hi')
```

But it makes more sense to define a method on the class instead.

```py
class MyClass:
    def hi(self):
        print('hi')

MyClass().hi()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lambda` for simple functions.

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        myfunc = self
        myfunc.hi = lambda: print('hi')

myFunc = myClass()
myFunc.hi()
```

Comment: Python doesn't have anonymous multi-line functions like JS does.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple in python,

```
class MyClass:
    def func(self):
        print('hi')

c = MyClass()
c.func()
```